# Получить значения аргументов вызываемой фукнции

Tags: php, рефлексия

Использую в шаблонах в которых мне надо подключить попап в качестве маркера функцию:

```
Main_Registry::setVar('disclaimer', true);
```

По первому параметру в функции хочу определять какой текст для попапа доставать из базы(шаблон попапа один).
Как мне получить значение первого аргумента из другого метода, не меняя саму функцию setVar, не добавляя в нее `func_get_args()`?

Пробовал так через 
`reflection - new ReflectionParameter(array('Main_Registry', 'setVar'), 0);` - но это возвращает аргумент а не значение аргумента в вызове функции.

Comment: Возможно есть идеи как иначе сделать маркеры?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

мапить параметры . Вот как вариант :

```
class Main_Registry
{

    public static function setVar($param , $bool = true){
        if($bool){
            return self::getResult($param);
        }
    }

    private static function getResult($param){
        $data = [
            'disclaimer' => "value 1",
            'main' => "value 2",
            'common' => "value 3",
        ];
        return ($data[$param] ? $data[$param] : "param {$param} not exist");
    }

}


echo(Main_Registry::setVar('disclaimer', true)."\n");
echo(Main_Registry::setVar('main', true)."\n");
echo(Main_Registry::setVar('empty', true)."\n");
```

на выходе : value 1 value 2 param empty not exist